# git push heroku master failed / RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm trying to push on an heroku folder with the command git push heroku master and it failed. My logs are :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

--> Move to your project folder

```
cd /location
```

First Check Your Status

```
git status
```

Add files

```
git add
```

Commit Now

```
git commit -m “Commit Now”
```

Use your Remote location / Address

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/projname.git
```

To see Remotes

```
git remote -v
```

Push now

```
git push <remote> <branch>
```

Force Push

```
git push -f <remote> <branch>
```

Answer (score -1):

## Update :

**Gemfile** :

```
group :development, :test do
 # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a  debugger console
 gem 'byebug'
 # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :development do
 # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console  %> in views
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
 gem 'spring'

end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '~> 0.11'
gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

except those gems all the other have to be on the top and we should use 'pg' gem for production and 'sqlite3' for development